# Trying to open offline pdf file from Titanium applicationDataDirectory local storage in WebView

Tags: appcelerator-alloy

First, I am trying to download PDF file, after the downloading gets  complete I am trying to open that PDF file into WebView from the downloaded path. but it shows error while I give the PDF's local storage file path. Below I paste my code and error while I am trying to open that file, please help me to find the correct solution Of this problem.

```js
var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient({
onload : function() {
var f = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, 'test.pdf');
if (!f.exists()) {

f.write(this.responseData);
filepath = f.nativePath;
Ti.API.info('new pdf file');
} else {
Ti.API.info('file exists' + f.nativePath);
var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
action : Ti.Android.ACTION_VIEW,
type : "application/pdf",
data : f.nativePath
});
try {
Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(intent);
} catch(e) {
Ti.API.debug(e);
alert('No apps PDF apps installed!');
}


}
},
timeout : 10000
});
xhr.open('GET', 'http://www.appcelerator.com/assets/The_iPad_App_Wave.pdf');
xhr.send();
```

Comment: did you find a solution for it @anup?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem with Appcelerator on Android. The problem is:

- Android does not have a built-in PDF viewer (unlike iOS)
- The data directories are private to Appcelerator, and not readable by any external PDF viewer.

To get around this, the PDF has to be copied (using code) to the Android device's external storage (e.g. an SD card) and opened from there. This will be pretty impossible to emulate, and unless you have a device which has an SD card in it, this isn't going to work.

I'm still searching for a solution to this problem which works with Appcelerator's newer SDK (5.5.1 -> 6.0.2).

I'm sure (like me) you'll have trawled the web looking for answers and come across things like:

https://archive.appcelerator.com/question/99031/how-to-open-pdf-file-saved-inside-app-directory-in-android-mobile

http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2015/08/appcelerator-pdf-viewer-demo/

But I can't seem to make any of them work.